# Conectar nodejs con mysql

Tags: mysql, nodejs, mysql-workbench

[image: Error un poco mas resumido]

Buenos dias,
tengo el siguiente problema al querer conectar nodejs a la base de datos (mysql) al momento de iniciar mi aplicación me salta el error que se encuentra en la imagen como puedo solucionar este problema

Comment: El error en una imagen es bastante ilegible, por favor edita y agregalo junto con el código mínimo necesario como texto por favor, checa [ask]

Answer (score 0):

Ejecuta la siguiente query en MYSQL Workbench

```
ALTER USER 'root'@'localhost' IDENTIFIED WITH mysql_native_password BY 'password'
```

Donde `root` es tu usuario, `localhost` tu URL y `password` tu contraseña.

Luego ejecuta esta consulta para actualizar los privilegios:

```
flush privileges;
```

Intenta conectarte usando nodejs después de hacer esto.
Si esto no funciona, prueba sin la parte @'localhost'.

fuente: https://stackoverflow.com/questions/50093144/mysql-8-0-client-does-not-support-authentication-protocol-requested-by-server